# Python Script + CGI + Xampp - not executing

Tags: python, apache, xampp, cgi

I'm trying execute my python script:

```
#!C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35-32/python.exe
print("Content-Type: text/html")
print ("""
    <TITLE>CGI script ! Python</TITLE>
    <H1>This is my first CGI script</H1>
    Hello, world!
"""
)
```

but the result is:

[image: result]

I tried configure Apache and add to httpd.conf line:

```
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
```

But it doesn't help.
Do you have any idea what may be wrong?

Comment: read Apache CGI doc. as I remeber it runs scripts only in folder `/cgi-bin/`

Comment: BTW: `mod_cgi` runs all types of scripts - Python, Perl, PHP, etc.. There is also `mod_python` only for scripts in Python. And `mod_wsgi` for Python Web Frameworks like `Flask`, `Django`, etc. which are more usefull.

Comment: BTW: `Flask`, `Django`, etc. have built-in servers so (for test or private use) you can run it without Apache and all this problems.